# Spring security login request giving a 404

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

I'm trying to implement a custom authentication mechanism using Spring security.

I have created my own implementation of the `UserDetailsService` which fetches the User

```
@Component
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

...

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        AccountResponse accountResponse = this.userService.getAccount(username);
        CustomUserDetails userDetails = new CustomUserDetails();
        userDetails.setUsername(accountResponse.getAccountId());
        return userDetails;
    }
}
```

Then I have created an implementation of the `AuthenticationProvider` which calls another method to do the password checking and returns a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` if passwords match

```
@Component
public class VeireAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

...
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String username = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        UserDetails userDetails = this.customUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        boolean authenticated =
                this.authenticationService.authenticate(userDetails.getUsername(), password);
        if (authenticated) {
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, password, userDetails.getAuthorities());
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And here is my security filter:

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
        return http.build();
```

I'm trying to utilize Spring's internal login API but for some reason I am getting a 404 on making a POST request to `http://localhost:8080/context-path/login` with username and password in the request body

Answer (score 0):

you need enable formLogin:

```
http.formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
@Autowired
private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

@Bean
public VeireAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {

       VeireAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new VeireAuthenticationProvider();
       authProvider.setUserDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
       return authProvider;
}
```

in your security filter add authentication provider

```
 http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).